# Jsp show element on condition

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to check that attribute in http session storage called "username" is there/not there in http session storage.
If it is in http session storage it will show a button.
If is not in http session storage the button should not be shown.

I have tried the following methods, both do not seem to work

First method: Review button shows up when "username" both when "username" is in http storage and not in http storage

```
<%
                String username1 = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
                
                %>
                <c:if test = "${username1.length()!=0}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #887775; border: none;" id="myBtn">Write a review</button>
                </c:if>
```

Second method: Review button does not show up at all whether "username" is there or not there in http session storage

```
<%
                String username1 = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
                
                %>
                <c:if test = "${username1.isEmpty()==true}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #887775; border: none;" id="myBtn">Write a review</button>
                </c:if>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your log? Can you try `request.getSession().getAttribute("username")`?

Comment: Please completely stop using old fashioned Scriptlet `<%...%>`. These variables are not available in EL `${...}` at all and mixing the Scriptlet and EL approaches will only confuse yourself for nothing. Just use `${not empty username}` right away.